# Android's string hash doesn't match serverisde's

Tags: java, php, android, hash

I'm developing an Android app and I need to send some data from server to Android device.

To prevent app from downloading too much data,I wrote a php service, which takes hash (md5 hash of last downloaded data), provided by Android and compares it to latest data's hash on server. If hashes match each other, it prints 'no_new_data', otherwise it prints latest data. Php uses md5($string) method to calculate hash - this part seems to work fine.

The problem is that hash calculated on device never matches server's one - it is wrong, even though string seems to be same. I tried even with changing encoding but it didn't help.

My md5 java code:
     public static String md5(String base){
        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            md.update(base.getBytes());

```
        byte byteData[] = md.digest();

        //convert the byte to hex format method 1
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++) {
            sb.append(Integer.toString((byteData[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }

        //System.out.println("Digest(in hex format):: " + sb.toString());

        //convert the byte to hex format method 2
        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i=0;i<byteData.length;i++) {
            String hex=Integer.toHexString(0xff & byteData[i]);
            if(hex.length()==1) hexString.append('0');
            hexString.append(hex);
        }
        return hexString.toString();
    }catch (Exception e){
        return "a";
    }
}
```

Thnks :)

Comment: I am running into the same issue, I've tried Google's built in Hash function: HashCode hc = Files.asByteSource(filename).hash(Hashing.md5()); with no success

Comment: I figured it out, when I was writing the image to the server I was adding and extra "\r\n" to my upload stream.  I debugged this using and empty file whose hash should always be d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes md5 hash is different from serverside hash. Try this method.

```
    public static String getMD5Hash(String s) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    String result = s;
    if (s != null) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5"); // or "SHA-1"
        md.update(s.getBytes());
        BigInteger hash = new BigInteger(1, md.digest());
        result = hash.toString(16);
        while (result.length() < 32) { // 40 for SHA-1
            result = "0" + result;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Never, ever use `String.getBytes()`, which depends on the platform-default charset, which is almost never what you want.  It seems likely that the platform default charset differs between Android and your server side.

Pass it a Charset instead, e.g.

```
myString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

if you have Java 7, or

```
myString.getBytes("UTF-8")
```

if you cannot.